# Google sheets conditional formatting to show selected text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So i've been trying to find a way to do this but struck a wall so hoping someone here might have a idea!
Problem:
We have a list of signatures that can be choosen with dropdown list in Google sheets. I want a conditional formatting to mark the ones already "used"
[image: image of the spreadsheet]

In the image above AAh, APu, ASa, KWa etc. are selected to the timeslots and locations in the top. Now I want the cells with the same name in G8:H23 to reflect that they are already in use.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `G8:H23`:

`=len(trim(G8)) * countif($B$3:$H$5; G8)`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGlwJJkBjeybreoLW5ss7p2bVUMu1Xp8zZR48DqSrbk/edit#gid=960414479) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmm, that only marks the empty cells

Comment: The formula will return a `false` value for _blank_ cells. It will return `true` for cells that are not blank but contain a _zero-length text string_. To make it work with both, use `=len(trim(G8)) * (countif($B$3:$H$5, G8) > 1)`.

Comment: Ah I see, not sure if we're misunderstanding each other or just me being stupid atm. I don't want to format blank cells or those with zero-length.
I've made a copy of the spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGlwJJkBjeybreoLW5ss7p2bVUMu1Xp8zZR48DqSrbk/edit?usp=sharing

The first tab TEMPLATE is the one, in G8:H23 is a list of acronyms, the same is selectable in the dropdown lists for each cell in B3:H5. When a name is selected in the later I want it to be shown somehow in the first list that it's already used.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: oOOoooohhh, that looks like magic :yey:
`=len(trim(G8)) * countif($B$3:$H$5; G8)` so first you check the length of the string without any blanks with `len(trim())`, Multiply that with every time the same word comes up in the area B3:H5?

I "thought" I had a good grasp of how sheet formulas work but this one is over my head! :D